# How can you stream music from Ubuntu to AirPlay speakers on your network with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, itunes, airplay

We have AirPlay speakers on our network, that can only be controlled using iTunes for Windows.  As I'm booted into Ubuntu, I'd like to be able to control the music being played. Is there any way to do this other than getting a VirtualBox to boot Windows?

Comment: Trying out with 12.04 and airbubble on a mb511 https://plus.google.com/u/0/107901537226351854008/posts/a5vamM8WYPQ
As you can see pulseaudio recognizes the droid but I got no sound out of it.

Answer (score 30):

First, install "PulseAudio Preferences" and the PulseAudio RAOP module if you don't already have them:

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs pulseaudio-module-raop
```

Now open up `paprefs` via the launcher (or `System > Preferences > PulseAudio Preferences`).  Now if you enable `Make discoverable Apple AirTunes sound devices available locally`, you can select AirPlay speakers like any other sound output device!

Comment: I have tried this solution but it doesn't worked out on Ubuntu 12.04 (my AirTunes speaker is a Freebox 6, maybe that's why it didn't work as they use Shareplay and not AirPlay).

Anyway, just to complete, you need "sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-raop" to have the box clickable.

Comment: Just got this working with AppleTV and box with airplay/airfoil speakers. This answer should be accepted @stevenmc

Comment: I know this is old, but it came up for me in Google trying to solve this issue. I had to install the raop module as above, and then restart pulseaudio for this to work, with the commands `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start`.

Comment: And for the dummies like me, don't forget install PulseAudio Preferences, of course.

Comment: And if you're wondering what's the package name for Pulseaudio Preferences it is `paprefs`

Comment: Worked for me on a fresh 19.10 but could not get it to work on an upgraded 19.10. No idea why.

Comment: FWIW, I can also not get this to stream to Rogue Amoeba's "Airfoil Satellite" app running on an iPhone (supposed to support the Airplay 1 protocol). I built everything required from source so have the latest versions.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 and it is crashing when selecting install, you need to setup a symlink as the folder name is changed. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1 /usr/lib/pulse-13.99`

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/gvtzpb/ubuntu_2004_lts_x86_64_trying_to_use_paprefs_but/

Comment: I confirm that it works on Ubuntu 21.10 : sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-15.0+dfsg1/ /usr/lib/pulse-15.0

Comment: Audio devices listing works, still no sound though. sigh. I'm on Pop OS 21.10