# How can I specify the password for AirPlay speakers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, airport, airplay

Since PulseAudio 11 there is [support for AirPort speakers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/11.0/). On older systems, you can [use `pulseaudio-module-raop`](https://superuser.com/questions/331126/how-can-you-stream-music-from-ubuntu-to-airplay-speakers-on-your-network-with-ub) or [`pulseaudio-raop2`](https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2) to be able to see AirPlay speakers in your Sound Settings and play music to them.

But how can we specify a password if the speakers are password protected? How exactly can you [specify this on the commandline](https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/71#issue-429687213)?